# Get lower bound using the chebyschev's inequaility.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality

I tried to solve a problem about chebyschev's inequality, but I don't know where i got wrong!

Here's the problem :

Find a lower bound for the probability that the average number shown on a die in 1000 tosses differs from 3.5 by 0.01.

And I attach the image that show how I solved.

[image]

the problem is that I got negative value for lower bound!
It makes sense since the probability is between [0,1], but the solution tells the correct answer is 0.29.

Please give me some advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original inequality tells that
$$
\mathbb{P}[|X-\mu|\ge k \sigma] \le \frac1{k^2}
\implies
\mathbb{P}[|X-\mu|< k \sigma] \ge 1-\frac1{k^2}
$$
Here, $X = \sum_{k=1}^{1000} X_k/1000$ where $X_k$ denotes the $k$th die roll. It's easy to see that $\mu = \mathbb{E}[X] = \mathbb{E}[X_k] = 3.5$ as needed for our problem. Last step is to determine the standard deviation.
$$
\sigma
 = \mathbb{Var}(X)
 = \frac{\mathbb{Var}(X_k)}{1000}
 = \frac{35/12}{1000}
 = \frac{7}{6000}.
$$
So your bound uses $k\sigma = 0.01 \iff k = 0.01/\sigma$ and we get
$$
\mathbb{P}[|X-3.5|\ge 0.01]
 \le \frac1{(0.01/\sigma)^2}
 = (100 \sigma)^2
 = \left(100 \cdot \frac{7}{6000} \right)^2
 = \left(\frac{7}{60} \right)^2
 = \frac{49}{3600}.
$$
Hence,
$$
\mathbb{P}[|X-3.5|< 0.1] \le 1-\frac{49}{3600} \approx 98.64 \%.
$$

Comment: Thanks for your time!!

Comment: @Prmouse made a mistake, please see the update